# Sets and combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

We are given 3 sets(balls) and 30 balls-10red,10blue,10green.In how many ways we can construct  3 sets of each having 10 elements so that:
1.in each set there is one main ball and other 9 which have the same colour
2.in every set the colour of the main ball is diffrent from the other 9 which have same colour
2.the colours of the main balls must be diffrent in each set
3.the colour of the other 9 balls in a set! must be  diffrent from each of the other sets 9 balls

example:Set 1=(1 Red and 9 green),
Set 2=( 1 Blue and 9 Red),
Set 3=(1 Green and 9 Blue)

Comment: I editted my answer, is it clear?

Comment: Yes!it is thanks

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the three main balls must all have distinct colors. There are $10^3$ ways to select which are going to be the main balls of each color. After this has been done you just need to select for each main ball which is going to be the color of the balls accompanying that main ball. There are $2$ ways to do this, this is because if the red ball is accompanied by the blue balls then the green balls must be accompanied by the red balls and the blue balls by the green balls. The other option is when the red ball is accompanied by the green ball.

Thus the answer is $10^3\cdot 2$.

Notice that if the question was with $k$ balls per color and $c$ colors the answer would be $k^c\times!c$ where $!c$ denotes the number of derrangements on a set of $c$ objects.